# I need to undo an action past a refactoring action aka Global Action (*Fix Name Violation)

Tags: visual-studio

I really need to undo an action that is past a refactoring action in Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise. The refactoring action is recorded in the Undo history as `*Fix Name Violation: NUM_ATTRIBUTES` which is a `const` field that I didn't type in all caps according to the naming convention. To adhere to the naming convention so it would stop bugging me I fixed, but I had cut a **huge** portion of the code to paste in another file before doing that (I should have copied it instead, but I distractedly cut it), but somehow it's not in my clipboard any more.

The class from where I cut the code is from my sister's scientific work (she's getting her master's degree) and I play with her stuff often just to see how it works, this had never happened before. Please help. I'm desperate and I know being desperate is not relevant but I'm very emotional right now.

It's fixed, I've found out there's a clipboard history.

Answer (score 0):

There's a `Show Clipboard History` under the `Edit` menu. I've found it. If that ever happens to you (you can't undo a clipboard action past a global not-undoable action that's the solution.